# reset password on allied telesis 8000s

Tags: switch, password-reset

I have around 10 of these switches. I should reset the passwords on these. I can't find a solution for this. The company told me to do it via the bootloader, but I don't have access on it. Is there anyone who know the process?

Comment: What about the web frontend? Here is the [manual](https://www.alliedtelesis.com/sites/default/files/documents/installation-guides/at001364.pdf).

Comment: When I reset the switch via the button it still keeps the password it had. Also, via browser I don't have access to reset the password, because I don't have the password to log in first

Comment: Ok, I guess default user `manager`, password `friend` doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't work :/

Comment: any ideas how to solve this?